# estimating a function for values in the text files

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have many text files in the directory(*.txt). And each text files consists of string and float values as given below.

```
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.8  1.856  8.9354
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.1  2.866  2.9354
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.0  5.856  9.9854
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.2  4.876  2.9454
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.7  2.856  6.9854
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.4  4.896  2.9554
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.3  2.856  8.9854
```

I want to estimate a function for every values in the 4th column(i want to take it as z) and want output to be saved in the extreme right of the same file

for example if i want to calculate my function with above data set then i need output like

```
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.8  1.856  8.9354    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.1  2.866  2.9354    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.0  5.856  9.9854    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.2  4.876  2.9454    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.7  2.856  6.9854    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.4  4.896  2.9554    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.3  2.856  8.9854    output
```

and same thing i wan to to do for every .txt file in the directory.

My function i designed as follows:

```
 m=1
 n=2
 o=4
 p=9
def  some_estimation(z):
     
     res=m*n*o*p+z
     return  res
#want to calculate the above func for every z value(4th column) of every .txt files in directory #and want to save the same 

for z_value in  /home/lijun/data/*.txt[3]:
    out=some_estimation(z_value)
    with open file(*.txt)
```

but it doesnot do what i expect.I expect some expert may help me on this.Thanks.

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: its mentioned in the description /home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.8  1.856  8.9354    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.1  2.866  2.9354    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.0  5.856  9.9854    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.2  4.876  2.9454    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.7  2.856  6.9854    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.4  4.896  2.9554    output
/home/lijun/data/2015_0.2_SWE.txt  2.3  2.856  8.9854    output

Comment: i can see that what is the actual value inplace of `output`?

Comment: that is res value

Comment: `some_estimation()` function is not using the formal arguments. call with any arguments it will always return same value

Comment: it should use some global values....constants

Comment: i mean m,n,o,p are constants

Comment: Seems there would be three inputs from each file that would be used in your function `some_estimation` but your function signature shows four inputs (m, n, o, p).  As mentioned, these inputs aren't used but are overwritten by your reassigning m, n, o, p inside the function.  And what is z (also inside the function)?

Comment: m,n,o,p are constant and i will take these as global variables

Comment: @lijun--so how are you distinguishing between the constants m,n,o,p and the arguments m, n, o, p in `some_estimation`?

Comment: I JUST HAVE TO TAKE THESE OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION...

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: @lijun--just saw your update which clarified the issues.  Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution with an explanation of steps

**Code**

```
import os

def  some_estimation(z):
     return  m*n*o*p + z

# constants
m = 1
n = 2
o = 4
p = 9
directory = "data"    # directory path (if data is a subdirectory of current working directory)
                      # if it's in the current working directory, use directory = "."
                      # or you can specify an absolute path

# Loop over files in directory
# using listdir (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm)
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith("SWE.txt"):      # optional (only passes files ending in SWE.txt)
                            
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as fin: 
                                                        # file opened for reading only
            line = fin.readline()                       # read file line
            a, b, c = [float(v) for v in line.split()]  # convert file values to float
            out = some_estimation(c)                    # perform calculation using last value
            
        # writing back to same file (open fle for writing)
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(f'{a} {b} {c} {out}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the results into a separate file so that you don't mess up the original. As in:

```py
with open("in.txt", "r") as infile, open("out.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        a, b, c, d = line.split()
        b, c, d = float(b), float(c), float(d)
        result = ... # do stuff with b, c, and d
        outfile.write(f"{line}  {result}\n")
```

Comment: how to append the directory path where .txt files are there

Comment: Do you mean like `open("C:\\some\\path\\to\\files\\in.txt", "r")`?

Comment: my .txt files are present inside /home/lijun/data/ directory  ...i am using linux